# Controller can not find partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

So I have a controller called myPartiaViewController with the path

Controllers/myPartiaViewController.cs

and I have a partial view, _mypartialView, inside a folder, myPartialView, that is inside another folder, MainView, in the Views folder

Views/MainView/myPartialView/_myPartialView.cshtml

I have a method in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult myPartialView()        
    return PartialView("MainView/myPartialView/_myPartialView.cshtml", model);}
}
```

For some reason my controller can not resolve the partial view. what going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `return PartialView("~/Views/MainView/PartialView/_myPartialView.cshtml", model);`

it's the `~` that does it. Otherwise you'll look for a top-level `MainView` folder, which is not as intended.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that is right.  The ~ starts from the site root.  So, for this view, his path should be "~/Views/MainView/PartialView/_myPartialView.cshtml".  His is broken because he is not even using the tilda in his code example.

Comment: @Tommy: yeah, possible. I'm not entirely sure anymore myself so we'll see when he responds. If he does, I'll edit it to make sure it reflects the correct answer (although I believe you're correct).

Comment: Thanks guys, sometimes I just want to slap myself.